# How to keep google open using Python webbrowser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to open several google pages through python webbrowser, and I've gotten it to work, but after opening all the pages, google simply closes unless I manually click it. Why is this happening? Help is appreciated, and thank in advance.

```
import pyautogui as py
import keyboard as key
import time

chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome',None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))


def n_t():
    py.hotkey('ctrl', 't')

def m_t():
    py.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')

def gogle():
    webbrowser.get('chrome').open('gmail.com')
    py.press('enter')
    time.sleep(5)
    n_t()
    py.write('www.youtube.com')
    py.press('enter')
    n_t()
    py.write('hangouts.google.com/authuser=2')
    py.press('enter')
    n_t()
    py.write('stackoverflow.com')
    py.press('enter')
    m_t()

gogle()
```

Comment: It didnt close for me though. There maybe some other error due to which your chrome is crashing

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
webbrowser.open('https://gmail.com')
webbrowser.open('https://youtube.com')
webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: it shows the same thing - After opening all the tabs, chrome just closes itself.

Comment: Then you have to do some QA thing. like try it on any other browser, restart your system, clear the cache, etc, because this piece of code (yours too) works fine everywhere I tried.